# I am receiving a nil string parameter in iPhone4S when same code works on simulator and on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a view where I display various text and image depending on the variable set.
The same code works fine on the simulator and and on the iPad but on an iPhone 4S I get the following:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
The text file is spelled correctly and is in the bundle

Here is the code I am using and have used similar in other parts of the program and is working fine

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_textfot ofType:@"txt"];

NSString *plainText = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];

_textView.text = plainText;
```

Comment: Use a debugger.  In short set a break point on the call to `initFileURLWithPath` and check the string.  If it's `nil` then move up the stack until you can figure out why the string is `nil`.  There is nothing we can do to help you as you are not asking a answerable question.

Comment: There might be the file name is not correct (due to case sensitivity). The bundle name of file might have any Capital or small Alphabet. It will work on simulator but on device if you are taking path of a bundle file then you have to use the exact name of file as it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_textfot 
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* plainText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: filePath
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

_textView.text = plainText;
```